# Custom UIView with @IBInspectable func or Selector

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder, ibinspectable

I'm working with Swift and learning about **@IBInspectable**. I would like to know if it's possible create a custom view that allow other views and viewControllers to set a inner button action, as a ViewController links an IBAction directly to a button that it has.

I can create a **@IBInspectable** in my custom view with Selector type, but it's not visible to other classes in Interface Builder.

```
@IBInspectable private var touchUpInside =
NSSelectorFromString("didClickButton") {
   didSet {
        button.addTarget(self, action: "touchUpInside", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   }
}
```

But not visible

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Same as
[IBDesignable… adding custom actions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799945/ibdesignable-adding-custom-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only types that are `IBInspectable` are: booleans, strings, numbers (primitives and types), `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, `CGRect`, `UIColor`, `NSRange`, and `UIImage`.

`NSSelector` isn't a valid type.

Even if it was it wouldn't show up in the outlets inspector but the attributes inspector. You posted a screen shot of the outlets inspector.

Comment: Thanks Sean. What I really wanted is to link an Action via @IBAction like UIButton does, but tried a lot and couldn't get it. DO you know if it's possible from a custom view?