# IBDesignable... adding custom actions?

Tags: xcode, swift, ibaction

I'm new to Xcode and I assume there's a way to do it but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have made a custom control by subclassing UIView and using IBDesignable.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to send events from within my control to a IBAction outside of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subclass UIControl not UIView. Once Interface Builder sees an UIControl subclass then send events section and actions will be available.

[Accessing the Control’s Targets and Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW19)